# How to replace multiple characters from all columns of a Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing multiple columns.

```
>>> df.take(1)
[Row(A=u'{dt:dt=string, content=Prod}', B=u'{dt:dt=string, content=Staging}')]
```

I want to remove both curly braces `{` and `}` from values of column 'A' and 'B' of `df`. I know we can use:

```
df.withColumn('A', regexp_replace('A', '//{', ''))
df.withColumn('A', regexp_replace('A', '//}', ''))
df.withColumn('B', regexp_replace('B', '//}', ''))
```

How do I replace characters dynamically for all columns of Spark dataframe? (Pandas version is shown below)

```
df = df.replace({'{':'', '}':''}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use proper regular expression:

```
df.withColumn("A", regexp_replace("A", "[{}]", ""))
```

Comment: How do we apply the above statement to multiple columns all at once? Let's say I have 10 columns in my data frame.

Answer (score 1):

To modify a dataframe `df` and apply `regexp_replace` to multiple columns given by `listOfColumns` you could use foldLeft like so:

```
val newDf = listOfColumns.foldLeft(df)((acc, x) => acc.withColumn(x, regexp_replace(col(x), ..., ...)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a column expression to every column of the dataframe in PySpark, you can use Python's list comprehension together with Spark's `select`. E.g.:

```py
df.select([column_expression for c in df.columns])
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('{dt:dt=string, content=Prod}', '{dt:dt=string, content=Staging}')],
    ['A', 'B'])

df = df.select([F.regexp_replace(c, '[{}]', '').alias(c) for c in df.columns])

df.show(truncate=0)
# +--------------------------+-----------------------------+
# |A                         |B                            |
# +--------------------------+-----------------------------+
# |dt:dt=string, content=Prod|dt:dt=string, content=Staging|
# +--------------------------+-----------------------------+
```